# Retrieve Fields of a Linked Entry - Contentful

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, contentful

As the title says, is there a way to view the fields of a linked entry in one query? For example, I query the following url:

```
https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/{spaceid}/entries/{entryid}?access_token={accesstoken}
```

and only get the fields associated with the entry I explicitly queried for. It only shows the meta data for linked entries. How can I write one url query that shows all fields of both the explicit entry and the linked entries?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out: I needed to add the url parameter:

```
&locale=*
```

which shows nested fields for entries.